# Batch in Windows always stop at first command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following batch (.bat) file for Command Prompt in Windows.
The script runs but after the first command it stops. I have also tried adding `&&` between command only first command is execute.

I need to runs every command in the .bat in order.. any ideas ho to fix it?

```
   :: task 1
    cd C:\buildscripts
    build.bat profile=C:\Projects\netventic\trunk\lib\test\test.profile.js

    :: task 2
    cd C:\build
    del /s *.uncompressed.js

    :: task 3
    cd C:\build
    copy C:\a.js C:\build\test\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is `CALL` :

```
    :: task 1
    cd C:\buildscripts
    CALL build.bat profile=C:\Projects\netventic\trunk\lib\test\test.profile.js

    :: task 2
    cd C:\build
    del /s *.uncompressed.js

    :: task 3
    cd C:\build
    copy C:\a.js C:\build\test\
```

Comment: May I ask you... Why to use CALL in order to continue with the batch ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GibboK - without call the cmd start reading the commands in the second batch and when reach the `EOF` it takes it as a stop.With `CALL` you create a subcontext of the cmd and when it finishes it returns the control to the parent context. Rather a limitation of the batch files.